# phantomjs screen capture for pdf - canvas scaling

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, phantomjs

i use phantomjs to make a pdf out of the content on my site. And it looks great with canvas as the exception.

in my print.css / media css i have the canvas to 100%

```
canvas {
height : 100%!important;
width  : 100%!important;
}
```

the canvas / content of canvas (which is a chart generated by chart.js) looks stretched / out of focus.

From reading various post i noticed that setting sizing through css is a no go, and i instead have to have it in-tag or set it through javascript directly on the canvas element.

however, thats not really an option since its already scaled/sized perfectly on the site. If i dont have the 100% height width, the canvas dont get jagged, but its WAY too big for my pdf format.

Whats the right way to go about fixing this, getting a crisp canvas for my screen capture which is sized for A4 / Standard pdf format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a canvas the css 'height' and 'width' element determine the size of the literal DOM element `<canvas>` NOT the size of the display within. In order to set this try something like this:

```
// grab canvas attribute
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// size the display appropriately
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// don't forget to account for the window size changing later on
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}, false);
```

Comment: tried to apply it, but still dosent change the size in my pdf / phantomjs capture :/